# How to auto run a program on a particular time without human interaction?

Tags: c#, sql

I want to check status of customers , and update all company's employees record on the basis of status at some particular time. I succeeded with that in `sql Agents`. But our boss said that no one `web hosters` are providing `sql agents` in shared. So find any other alternate process to run it.
So I created one window form and coded in `FormLoad` event like below.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection cnn;
            SqlCommand cmd;
            string sql = null;    
            connetionString = "Data Source=SERVER1;Initial Catalog=crm;User ID=sa;Password=elife@123";
            sql = "AutoCheckExpiry_ForPayment";    
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Dispose();
                cnn.Close();               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }                        
        }
```

then got `.exe` file of this application and attached into `task scheduler`, but its not working..
So is there another alternate for this?

Comment: Create job in your database. No need to have an application to run this for you

Comment: I cant get agents in shared..

Comment: Please change your password as soon as possible -:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a `timer` in your program which will run continuously & check the time if matches, then execute your code.

Or use the `windows scheduler`. Just schedule your script into the windows scheduler & it will execute your program at the scheduled time.

Comment: for timer control application have to always on run mode but my application not always on run mode.

Comment: so how to do with windows schdeular..What ever I did the process above mentioned which is not working.

Comment: For the 1st way, you keep your process running every time. If you use the second way, you will be dependent on windows. So wherever you install your software, you will have to configure the scheduler. Here is the tutorial http://www.7tutorials.com/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard

Comment: cant we run just program without display any window?

Comment: end of the your code just write 'This.close()' then your form will never display.

Comment: Yes, you can. Just add this code on form load `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; this.ShowInTaskbar = false;`